# ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework: Generic model-independent controller class implemented with actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-database-first

I'm trying to implement this kind of mechanizm:

Model has bit field: `is_active`, so I'm using it to toggle visibility on the main form. The action in controler is like:

```
public ActionResult Toggle(int id)
    {
        Country country = _db.Countries.Find(id);
        country.is_active = country.is_active == null ? true : !country.is_active;
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I want my admin lookup controllers to derive from that generic class and use the implementation from it for common actions like toggle.

I've already created ITogglable interface that has `ActionResult Toggle(int id)` so I'm implementing it inside particular controler (`CountryController : Controller, ITogglable`), but I have to implement it every time. Instead I would more like my CountryController, RegionController, etc derive from a generic class (i.e. `Togglable`) that has these kind of methods already implemented like:

```
public virtual ActionResult Toggle(int id)
{
    CurrentModelTypeUsedInController lookup = _db.CurrentModelTypeUsedInController.Find(id);
    lookup .is_active = lookup .is_active == null ? true : !lookup.is_active;
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Is this even possible? I have no idea how to make it lookup-independant so I do not have to provide type of `CurrentModelTypeUsedInController` each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a couple of abstractions to achieve this.

Firstly you will need an abstraction that defines `is_active`, such as

```
public interface IActive 
{ 
    bool is_active { get; set; } 
}
```

And all of the types such as `Country` and `CurrentModelTypeUsedInController` will need to implement this abstraction

```
public class Country : IActive 
{
    public bool is_active { get; set; }
}
```

And with this in place we define the generic controller. The key point here is the *generic constraint* (`IActive`) that is placed on *generic type* (`TModelType`). By defining that all types of `TModelType` must implement `IActive` the code knows that the type is guaranteed to expose a property named `is_active`

```
public class AbstractController<TModelType> : Controller 
    where TModelType : class, IActive
{
    private readonly DbContext _db;

    public AbstractController()
    {
        _db = new DbContext("connection");
    }

    public ActionResult Toggle(int id)
    {
        TModelType instance = _db.Set<TModelType>().Find(id);
        instance.is_active = instance.is_active == null ? true : !instance.is_active;
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

And each controller can derive from `AbstractController<>`

```
public sealed class CountryController : AbstractController<Country>
{
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to say, that you're awesome!