# MVC: Implementing Generic Controllers and Views. Empty values while enumeration in view issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, generics, view

Continuing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755523/asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-generic-model-independent-controller-class-implem) (thanks @qujck) I've implemented Generic controller which looks like this:

```
public class GenericLookupController<TModelType> : Controller where TModelType : GenericLookupModel //GenericLookupController.cs
```

It has all common actions for handling most common tasks in lookup tables like CRUD, toggling active state and such. 
I'm trying now to create also generic views for those generic lookup tables. 
Model type is `GenericLookupModel` which basically looks like this:

```
public class GenericLookupModel : IActive, CustomField
{
    public bool is_active { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public DateTime? created_on { get; set; }
    public string created_by { get; set; }
    public DateTime? updated_on { get; set; }
    public string updated_by { get; set; }
    public int id {get;set;}
}
```

So let's take for example country lookup controller and model:

```
public partial class Country : GenericLookupModel //country lookup model
{
}
```

and controller:

```
public class CountryController : GenericLookupController<Country> //CountryController.cs
{
}
```

Actions are working fine for those, but I have a problem with views. For `Index` action I'm using:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index() //GenericLookupController.cs
{
    var model = _db.Set<TModelType>().ToList();
    return View("__GenericLookupIndex",model);
}
```

and the `__GenericLookupIndex` looks like that:

```
@model IEnumerable<GenericLookupModel> @*__GenericLookupIndex.cshtml*@
@{
    Layout = "_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

...

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.value)
        </td>
        <td>
            @{
                if (item.is_active)
                {
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                }
                else
                {
                    <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
                }
            }
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.created_on)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.created_by)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.updated_on)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.updated_by)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { item.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs" }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Deactivate/Activate", "Toggle", new { item.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning btn-xs" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The issue is that `item` doesn't have enumerated values from `Model` in the line with `foreach`. I've tried to do workaround and instead of `@foreach (var item in Model)` I did `@foreach (Country item in Model)` and that works but this denies the whole Generic idea. How can I fix it, so that I don't have to specify the type explicitly in the view and get the data properly? Please advice.

**Update:**
The application doesn't throw any errors, but I don't get proper values while enumeration. Please look into screenshots below:

1) [Empty table generated by view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEthD.png)
2) [Model variable in Watch window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQtEb.png)
3) [Enumerated item variable from Model in Watch window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyDhv.png)

Comment: What exactly is the error you're seeing? Is it shown on run-time only?

Comment: Application doesn't throw any errors. The `item` variable is filled with default values instead of values taken from enumerated Model. So I end up with table filled with blank/default values. I.e. Button for edit navigates to `/Edit/0` insead of `/Edit/10` and column with value is blank insead of i.e. Israel

I'll provide some screenshots in few minutes

Comment: Did you make sure that in Controller/Action the values are actually there? Also, show your full `Country` class.

Comment: Yes, values are there when returned in actions, the `Country` class comes from Entity Framework and I'm using partials to implement genericity. Please take a look on screenshots provided in the update.

Comment: Please include all `Country` partials as well.

Comment: I think it's more about unable to cast to proper type while enumeration, but here you go: [click](http://pastebin.com/g4CT3sQL)

Comment: Does `Country` derives from `GenericLookupModel` or directly from `CustomField`? In your question you posted one partial in the link you posted another.

Comment: You can create multiple partials for one class and I've posted you both declarations. And as you can see in the post Country derives from `GenericLookupModel`, which derives from `CustomField`.

Comment: Did you try `@foreach (GenericLookupModel item in Model) `?

Comment: It does the same as `Model` is type of `IEnumerable<GenericLookupModel>`, so `var item` is equal to `GenericLookupModel item`